# Is a block formatting context created by an element with a border?

Tags: html, css, border

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Block_formatting_context) I know that a block formatting context is created by one of the following:

- the root element or something that contains it
- floats (elements where float is not none)
- absolutely positioned elements (elements where position is absolute or fixed)
- inline-blocks (elements with `display: inline-block`)
- table cells (elements with `display: table-cell`, which is the default for HTML table cells)
- table captions (elements with `display: table-caption`, which is the default for HTML table captions)
- elements where overflow has a value other than `visible`
- flex boxes (elements with `display: flex` or `inline-flex`)

But I have a question regarding the following code:

```
<div style='background:grey;border:black 1px dotted;width:400px'>
    <div style='margin:20px;background:red;'>the parent create a bfc</div>
</div>
<div style='background:grey;width:400px'>
    <div style='margin:20px;background:red;'>why?</div>
</div>
```

The first div element creates a BFC, but the only difference between them is that the first div has a border. Why?

Comment: @user2253835: It says right in the title: "block formatting context".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of the two `div` elements is creating its own BFC. There is absolutely nothing in your code that suggests that the first `div` element is creating its own BFC — having a border alone does not cause an element to establish its own BFC.

What the border is doing is blocking [margin collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). This means the margins of the child element do not combine with those of the parent element; they're constrained within the parent element box.

Answer (score 1):

I'm absolutely agreed with [@BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381473/can-a-block-formatting-context-created-by-an-element-with-a-border/16381700#16381700)

> What the border is doing is blocking [margin collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins). This means the margins of the child element do not combine with those of the parent element; they're constrained within the parent element box.

But I'm giving you here the solution if you want to solve that problem as what you want. Just add `overflow: hidden;` to your second div which won't collapse the margin.

```
<div style='background:grey;border:black 1px dotted;width:400px'>
    <div style='margin:20px;background:red;'>the parent create a bfc</div>
</div>
<div style='background:grey;width:400px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <div style='margin:20px;background:red;'>why?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ,Now I know  border separate them :-) [W3C Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

Comment: Not only border but also if you give padding value it will also be okay! But overflow properties is strongly recommended. When you apply this property, no problem would appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misled by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Inline_formatting_context).

According to the accepted answer, this is incorrect. I also think so because it conflicts with the definition of [BFC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

[image]